# Infinite Spiral of Numbers: Printing neighbors

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I start?  No clue how to write this, particularly because I do not understand what is meant by "dimension."  Would greatly appreciate some help.

Consider the natural numbers laid out in a square spiral, with 1 occupying the center of the spiral. The central 11 x 11 subset of that spiral is shown in the table below.

```
111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121
110 73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82
109 72  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  83
108 71  42  21  22  23  24  25  26  51  84
107 70  41  20  7   8   9   10  27  52  85
106 69  40  19  6   1   2   11  28  53  86
105 68  39  18  5   4   3   12  29  54  87
104 67  38  17  16  15  14  13  30  55  88
103 66  37  36  35  34  33  32  31  56  89
102 65  64  63  62  61  60  59  58  57  90
101 100 99  98  97  96  95  94  93  92  91
```

This spiral has several interesting features. The southeast diagonal has several prime numbers (3, 13, 31, 57, and 91) along it. The southwest diagonal has a weaker concentration of prime numbers (5, 17, 37) along it.

To construct the spiral we start with 1 at the center, with 2 to the right, and 3 below it, 4 to the left, and so on. A part of the problem for this assignment is to figure out the rule to fill the spiral for an arbirary size. Once you have that rule you can complete the rest of the assignment.

You will prompt the user for the following information:

Enter dimension: `57`
Enter number in spiral: `42`

The first line indicates the dimension of the square spiral. This number should be an odd number. If it is not then choose the dimension to be the next higher odd number. The second number must be in the range 1 and the square of the dimension. If the second number is not in that range, print an error message `Number not in Range`.

You will write the neigboring numbers of the second number in three lines. Each line will have three integers separated by a single white space. If the second number was `42`, then this should be your output:

```
72 43 44
71 42 21
70 41 20
```

If the second number was `64`, then this should be your output:

```
66 37 36
65 64 63
100 99 98
```

What if that second number was on the outer edge of the spiral, then print `Number on Outer Edge`.

Comment: Can you ask whoever wrote the assignment what they meant?

Comment: dimension seems to mean the size of the square, so if the given dimension is 57, you would use a 57 x 57 square, which is why the second number has to be between 1 and dimension^2. It has to be odd because there's a single number in the center.

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking it down step by step by what you think you need to do:

```
       1) scan 2d array for your number
       2) do algorithm to print spiral
            -print x numbers on row -1, print x numbers on row + 1
            -print y numbers on col -1, print y numbers on col + 1
       3) then start checking for special cases, like if number was in outer edge
```